# How do I syncronize folder A to folder B one time?

Tags: windows, directory, synchronization

Folder A is on my main desktop computer.  Folder B is on my networked laptop.  I'd like them to be the same, but I only want this synchronization done when I choose.  I don't want a constant check being made.

So let's say that on Saturday, I'm going to take my laptop on a trip.  I want its folder B to contain everything on my desktop's folder A.  Any files not currently on folder B should be copied from folder A.  Any files no longer on folder A should be deleted from folder B.  Creation/modification times aren't important.  Just existence or non-existence.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Sure. The easiest way is prob. to use some free folder syncing tools, maybe something like [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/).

Some file managers like [SpeedCommander](https://www.speedproject.com/) also have build in [synchronization support](https://www.speedproject.com/sc/#foobox-1/19/filesync).

Comment: That looks promising.  I'll give it a try!